# Modify how a tf.estimator.Estimator creates summaries for Tensorboard

Tags: tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to find out how I can modify the way a custom TensorFlow estimator creates event files for Tensorboard. Currently, I have the impression that, by default, a summary (containing the values of all the things (like typically accuracy) I'm following with tf.summary.scalar(...) ) is created every 100 steps in my model directory. The names of the event files later used by tensorboard look like
events.out.tfevents.1531418661.nameofmycomputer.

I found a routine online to change this behaviour and create directories for each run with the date and time of the computation, but it uses TensorFlow basic APIs:

```
logdir = "tensorboard/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + "/"
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir, sess.graph)
```

Is it possible to do something similar with a TF custom estimator?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to specify a directory for each evaluation run using `name` argument of the [`evaluate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#evaluate) method of `tf.estimator.Estimator`  e.g.:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn,
    model_dir=model_dir
)
eval_results = estimator.evaluate(
            input_fn=eval_input_fn,
            name=eval_name
            )
```

The event files for this evaluation will be saved in the directory inside `model_dir` named `"eval_" + eval_name`.

Answer (score -1):

Summary Writers are not needed for TensorFlow Estimators. The summary log of the model is written to the designated folder location using the `model_dir` attribute of `tf.Estimator` function when the `tf.Estimator.fit()` method is called.

In the example below, the selected directory to store the training logs is `'./my_model'`.

```
tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    model_fn,
    model_dir='./my_model',
    config=None,
    params=None,
    warm_start_from=None
)
```

Launch TensorBoard by running `tensorboard --logdir=./my_model` from the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what if I want to use the same Estimator object several times and store my summary logs each time in a different folder (having in its name the day and time of the run)?

Comment: I guess simply change the directory location of the Estimator attribute `model_dir`, and consequently run tensorboard from that directory.

Comment: I think that the `model_dir` attribute is fixed after the initialization. I tried `classifier.model_dir = "New_dir"` after having trained my estimator (called classifier) but it failed. I got "AttributeError: can't set attribute"

Comment: No. You can't call it that way, you have to run a new model, but this time, simply change the directory location in `model_dir`.

Comment: But I don't want to run a new model. I would like to have the results (for Tensorboard) of the same model saved each time in a different folder. But the graph and the checkpoint and the graph.pbtxt should always be in the same. This is possible with TF basic APIs but I don't know how to do it at Estimator APIs level.